# JQuery delete duplicates of an element

Tags: jquery

I have some labels on my form:

```
<label>8/22/2014</label> <!--label1-->
<label>8/22/2014</label> <!--label2-->
<label>8/23/2014</label> <!--label3-->
<label>8/24/2014</label> <!--label4-->
<label>8/25/2014</label> <!--label5-->
<label>8/25/2014</label> <!--label6-->
<label>8/26/2014</label> <!--label7-->
<label>8/26/2014</label> <!--label8-->
<label>8/26/2014</label> <!--label9-->
```

I want only first of each labels grouped by date to remain on the form and others
be deleted. according to the example above, these elements should remain on the form:

```
<label>8/22/2014</label> <!--label1-->
<label>8/23/2014</label> <!--label3-->
<label>8/24/2014</label> <!--label4-->
<label>8/25/2014</label> <!--label5-->
<label>8/26/2014</label> <!--label7-->
```

how can I do this?

Comment: Iterate over all elements. If the element has the same content as the one before, delete it. Do you have any specific question?

Comment: Actually my original code is much different than what i wrote here. I was working with `.each` and `.prev` and `.parent` to get this done, but using an array as @R.T. mentioned did the job. thank you.

Comment: You should always include what you have tried.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try this:

```
var seen = {};
$('label').each(function() {
    var str = $(this).text();
    if (seen[str])
        $(this).remove();
    else
        seen[str] = true;
});
```

**[JSFIDDLE DEMO](http://jsfiddle.net/fr79vjbz/1/)**

Answer (score 2):

```
$('label').each(function () {
    if ($(this).text() == $(this).prev().text()) $(this).remove()
})
```

**[jsFiddle example](http://jsfiddle.net/j08691/fr79vjbz/)**

Answer (score 0):

```
$(function(){
    var dates = [];
    $('label').each(function(){
        if(dates.indexOf($(this).html())>-1) {
            $(this).remove();
            return;
        }

        dates.push($(this).html());
    });
});
```

or use jquery.unique : http://api.jquery.com/jquery.unique/